# How to set xrange on command line in gnuplot

Tags: command-line, set, gnuplot, default-value, xrange

I have several gnuplot scripts that draw graphs for me. I need to set the same xrange values ​​on the command line for everyone gnuplot scripts.
I don't want to open each one separately.

Code in gnuplot scripts(name:tlakD.gnuplot):

```
set xdata time 
set timefmt "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M" # specify time string format
set xrange datum
set format x "%d/%m/%Y "
```

Command line attempt:
`gnuplot -e "datum='["1/1/19 12:00":"1/5/19 11:59"]'" tlakD.gnuplot`

Second attempt:
I removed the xrange.

Code in gnuplot scripts(name:tlakD.gnuplot):

```
set xdata time 
set timefmt "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M" # specify time string format
set format x "%d/%m/%Y "
```

Command line attempt:
`gnuplot -e "xrange='["1/1/19 12:00":"1/5/19 11:59"]'" tlakD.gnuplot`

An idea of ​​what I want:
`gnuplot -e "xrange='["1/1/19 12:00":"1/5/19 11:59"]'" tlakD.gnuplot ; vlhkosD.gnuplot; teplotaD.gnuplo and many more gnuplots scripts`
I want to run all scripts with the same xrange.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem you can specify a range `[...:...]` in one variable, but you can do so in 2 separate string variables:

```
gnuplot  -e a='"1/1/19 12:00"' -e b='"1/5/19 11:59]"'

set xrange [a:b]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to put the range command in a separate file and invoke both the range file and the plot file in the command.  You could even have a collection of range files and choose the one you want at the time of plotting.

```
 gnuplot setrange_1.gp tlakD.gp
```

It is not necessary to use the `-e` construct here. gnuplot will execute each file listed on the command line in the order given, as if they had been concatenated into a single larger file prior to execution.

Comment: I also tried this method, unfortunately it doesn't work.
Command line writes: Can't plot with an empty x range!

In separate file(name:nastav.gp) is :  `set xrange ["1/1/19 12:00":"1/5/19 11:59"]`
In command line: `gnuplot nastav.gp tlakD.gnuplo`

Comment: I assure you that the method works.  I suggest to start with a working sequence of commands, then split it into a first part in one file and a second part in another file.

Comment: You could also use the command line construct `cat file1 file2 | gnuplot`, although I can't think of any advantage to doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I created a `data.txt` file like this:

```
"2/1/2019 10:00:00" 4
"3/1/2019 10:00:00" 8
"4/1/2019 10:00:00" 16
"5/1/2019 10:00:00" 32
```

The commands I would run inside `gnuplot` would be:

```
set timefmt '"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"'
set xdata time
set xrange ['"1/1/2019 12:00"':'"1/5/2019 11:59"']
plot "data.txt" using 1:2
```

So, that means my `bash` command line would be:

```
gnuplot -p \
        -e "set timefmt '\"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S\"'"                    \
        -e "set xdata time"                                         \
        -e "set xrange ['\"1/1/2019 12:00\"':'\"5/1/2019 11:59\"']" \
        -e "plot \"data.txt\" using 1:2"
```

[image]